# Create a Toolstrip for each Toolstripbutton located on a main Toolstrip

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, toolstrip, toolstripbutton

I want to create a Toolstrip and for each ToolStripButton. I also want to create a Toolstrip below the first, in this way each Toolstrip dynamically appear when I click on a ToolStripButton.

I have tried to create the main Toolstrip with Visual Studio designer and for the other toolstrips below I tried to use a customize Toolstrip class. But when I tried to add them:

```
var cts = new CustomToolStrip();  
this.Controls.Add(cts);`
```

they appeared above of the main Toolstrip.

Here is my CustomToolStrip class:

```
public class CustomToolStrip : ToolStrip
    {
        public ToolStripSec()
        {
            this.GripStyle = ToolStripGripStyle.Hidden;
            this.Padding = new Padding(4, 2, 4, 2);
            this.AutoSize = true;
            this.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
            this.Location = new Point(0, 42);
            var tspr = new ToolStripProfessionalRenderer();
            tspr.RoundedEdges = false;
            this.Renderer = tspr;
        }
    }
```

Form:

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        public FormAccueil()
        {
            InitializeComponent(); //this method add the first toolstrip (TSMain)
            var r = new ToolStripProfessionalRenderer();
            r.RoundedEdges = false;
            TSMain.Renderer = r;

            var cts = new CustomToolStrip(); 
            this.Controls.Add(cts); // here is the problem
        }
}
```

Result:

http://s16.postimg.org/9kgh0xmh1/Capture.png

Toolstrip 1 and 2 both have the property dock = top.

What can I do to get the Toolstrip 2 below the Toolstrip 1 ?

Could someone guide me please...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the z-order:

```
this.Controls.Add(cts);
cts.BringToFront();
```